# Class Level Error Handler For DAO

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, error-handling

I am using Entity Framework. Below is an example of a list method for an Actors context in my ActorsDao class. If you imagine my application is like imdb, there will be CRUD methods for various other contexts such as Movies, Directors, Genres, Reviews, Studios etc.

Regardless of the method or context, I handle errors in the same way. Due to my many methods across many contexts, my catch section is always exactly the same.

Obviously, I could create an error handling class, put the code in there, and just call a method in that class from the catch block.

However, I'm wondering if there a way to omit the TRY...CATCH from each method and set up a global error handler for the methods in my entity framework layer?

I would only want this global error handler to handle these errors and not errors from the rest of the application.

I seem to remember in Java Spring, you could annotate a class or method with the name of a method, and all errors would be passed to that without the need of a TRY...CATCH. I'm wondering if there is something similar for .NET (or a third party library with such functionality)?

```
    public List<Actor> ListActors()
    {

        List<Actor> actorList = new List<Actor>();

        using (var context = new ActorContext())
        {
            try
            {
                actorList = context.Actors.ToList<Actor>();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Handle error code
            }
        }

        return actorList;

    }
```

**EDIT**

I did some more research and found this code from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4851985/1753877

```
private void GlobalTryCatch(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action.Invoke();
    }
    catch (ExpectedException1 e)
    {
        throw MyCustomException("Something bad happened", e);
    }
    catch (ExpectedException2 e)
    {
        throw MyCustomException("Something really bad happened", e);
    }
}

public void DoSomething()
{
    GlobalTryCatch(() =>
    {
        // Method code goes here
    });
}
```

Would using a delegate like this be OK? It certainly meets my requirements.

Comment: You could remove the `try/catch` block and implement something on the high layer, where you can your repositories or services. Maybe if you are using `asp.net mvc` you could use attributes to decorate your action on the controllers and handle any error on any layer on you architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class like this and extend the controller from this class.

**Error Handler class looks like this :**

```
package com.wes.essex.rest;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

import com.wes.essex.bean.ErrorResponse;

public class SkyNewsController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SkyNewsController.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleError(Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.info("start");
        LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
        error.setTimestamp(ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT));
        LOGGER.debug("error : {} ", error);
        ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> response = null;
        if (ex instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
            error.setReasonCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
            ConstraintViolationException constraintException = (ConstraintViolationException) ex;
            Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> set = constraintException.getConstraintViolations();
            String errorMessage = "Input Validation Failed:";
            for (ConstraintViolation<?> constraintViolation : set) {
                errorMessage += constraintViolation.getMessageTemplate() + ",";
            }
            errorMessage = errorMessage.substring(0, errorMessage.length() - 1);
            error.setErrorMessage(errorMessage);
            response = new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {
            error.setReasonCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
            error.setErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
            response = new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

**This would be the baean class for error response :**

```
package com.wes.essex.bean;

public class ErrorResponse {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5776681206288518465L;

    private String timestamp;
    private String errorMessage;
    private int reasonCode;

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public int getReasonCode() {
        return reasonCode;
    }

    public void setReasonCode(int reasonCode) {
        this.reasonCode = reasonCode;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
}
```